# SELECT data from multiple tables if a requirement is met in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

the title doesnt describe it that well, my problem:

I have 2 tables, one table for orders, the other for the product.
An order can have n products associated with it.

I want to select those orders, where **all** their associated products have a status (attribute of the product) greater or equal to x. (So I know that every product of my order is "ready" and the order can be processed further)

Every ordered product has an OrderID

Any tips?

e: Just started with SQL, dont bash me if this is a stupid question

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How are multiple products for an order represented?  I would expect an additional table, called something like `orderProducts` or `orderLines`.

Comment: For starters, show us the CREATE TABLE for both tables in question and the SELECT query you've written so far.

Comment: I think by that you just answered my question, I guess I should add a third table. Thanks! - how could I not think of that

Comment: select * from orders where not exists ( select an order line that is not not ready) NOTE: remember to link inner query.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of mindset.
You have to find the 'dual' form of your question ( -> double negation).
You need to find all the orders that have AT LEAST one line that is not ready.

Assuming your tables are the common:
*Order(**ID**,bla,bla,bla)* and *Order Line(**orderID, row#**, status, bla, bla) FK orderid references order.*
You can use this stub:

```
Select *
from orders O
where not exists ( select * from order_line OL 
                   where ol.orderID=O.orderID  --binding with outer query
                   and status <> 'ready' 
                  )
```

SIDE NOTE: my query will produce also empty orders, to filter them just add to outer query `and exists (select * from orderline oe where oe.orderid=o.orderid)`